# Firebase configuration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm developing an iOS application and my pod file looks like

```
platform :ios, '8.0'  
use_frameworks!

target 'MYAPP' do  
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'  
    pod 'Google/SignIn'  
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'  
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'  
end

target 'MYAPPTests' do  
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'  
    pod 'Google/SignIn'  
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'  
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'  
end

target 'MYAPPUITests' do  
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'  
    pod 'Google/SignIn'  
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'  
    pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.1'  
end
```

When I run the application and keep finding the following warning in the console:

> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet
>   been configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application
>   initialization. Read more: ".

So in my appdelegate, I had added `FIRApp.configure()` which results in a crash

> ' [Firebase/Messaging][I-IID001000] Firebase is not set up
>   correctly. Sender ID is nil or empty. 2017-06-14 18:25:37.044
>   MYAPP[10520:128089] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'com.firebase.instanceid', reason: 'Could not configure Firebase
>   InstanceID. Google Sender ID must not be nil or empty.''

Is it the `GoogleModbileAdsSDK` which required the Firebase config?
What am I missing here?

Comment: are you working with firebase?where is your firebase in pod?

Comment: actually I'm not using Firebase specifically. But I keep on getting the warning to setup Firebase. So I suspect it comes up due to some other SDK I use, probably Alamofire. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Alamofire has nothing to do with firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup
You need to add to the pod file the ones you need to use from database

Comment: i actually don't want to use the Firebase. So why is my console printing a warning to config Firebase?

Comment: I'm in the same boat... I actually DON'T want to use it... so turning off console dumping for Firebase would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install other google packages then use

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
```

it will only install the package require for googleSignIn

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code in AppDelegate.swift

```
override init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

instead of configureing in :

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```